# WebRTC: ontrack() not called on Safari with go-based peer

Tags: javascript, go, webrtc

I am trying to stream video through WebRTC from my golang backend (using [this WebRTC implementation](https://github.com/pion/webrtc)) to a client browser.

My implementation works on Chrome but does not on Safari because the `RTCPeerConnection.ontrack()` callback is never fired, despite the remote peer offering a video track. The ICE connection seems successful. When using Safari itself as the backend peer, `ontrack()` is called normally.

I've seen many people having issues with `ontrack()` not being called but none of them had this specific issue.

Here is a minimal reproducible example. To run it :

- Place `index.html` in your working directory
- Run `main.go`
- Visit `localhost:8080` with Chrome, notice the `on track called!` message that is printed in the console
- Visit the page using Safari, notice `ontrack()` is not called.

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/pion/webrtc/v3"
)

var localDescription webrtc.SessionDescription

func openConnection(offer *webrtc.SessionDescription) *webrtc.SessionDescription {
    peerConnection, err := webrtc.NewPeerConnection(webrtc.Configuration{
        ICEServers: []webrtc.ICEServer{
            {
                URLs: []string{"stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"},
            },
        },
    })
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    videoTrack, err := webrtc.NewTrackLocalStaticSample(webrtc.RTPCodecCapability{MimeType: webrtc.MimeTypeVP8}, "video", "pion")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    rtpSender, err := peerConnection.AddTrack(videoTrack)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    go func() {
        rtcpBuf := make([]byte, 1500)
        for {
            if _, _, rtcpErr := rtpSender.Read(rtcpBuf); rtcpErr != nil {
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    peerConnection.OnICEConnectionStateChange(func(connectionState webrtc.ICEConnectionState) {
        fmt.Printf("Connection State has changed %s \n", connectionState.String())
    })

    // `offer` received from browser
    err = peerConnection.SetRemoteDescription(*offer)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    answer, err := peerConnection.CreateAnswer(nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    gatherComplete := webrtc.GatheringCompletePromise(peerConnection)

    if err = peerConnection.SetLocalDescription(answer); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    <-gatherComplete

    return peerConnection.LocalDescription()
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/rtc", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        if r.Method != "POST" {
            rw.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
            rw.Header().Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*")
            return
        }

        offer := webrtc.SessionDescription{}
        err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&offer)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }

        answer := openConnection(&offer)
        err = json.NewEncoder(rw).Encode(answer)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    })

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        ui, err := os.ReadFile("./index.html")
        if err != nil {
            rw.Write([]byte("missing index.html next to main.go: " + err.Error()))
            return
        }

        rw.Write([]byte(ui))
    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

`index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <script>
        const pc = new RTCPeerConnection({
            iceServers: [
                {
                    urls: 'stun:stun.l.google.com:19302',
                },
            ],
        });

        pc.oniceconnectionstatechange = (e) => console.log(pc.iceConnectionState);

        pc.ontrack = (event) => console.log('on track called!');

        pc.onicecandidate = async (event) => {
            if (event.candidate === null) {
                const response = await fetch('/rtc', {
                    method: 'post',
                    body: JSON.stringify(pc.localDescription)
                })

                const body = await response.json()
                pc.setRemoteDescription(new RTCSessionDescription(body));
            }
        };


        // at least one track or data channel is required for the offer to succeed
        pc.createDataChannel('dummy');
        pc
            .createOffer({
                offerToReceiveVideo: true,
                offerToReceiveAudio: true,
            })
            .then(description => pc.setLocalDescription(description));
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Have the same with 15.2, however on 14.x and 16.x (or maybe just different computers) it seems to work fine. Did you manage to sort it out?